# readfile() fails because of SSL

Tags: php, ssl, curl, readfile

I'm using readfile() to serve a download from Rapidshare's API through my server. This is the relevant code:

```
readfile("http://rs$server_id$short_host.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=download&fileid=$file_id&filename=$file_name&login={$account['username']}&password={$account['password']}");
```

But when I request the page, I get this error:

```
Warning: readfile(http://rs869l34.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=download&fileid=3457766962&filename=some_file.rar&login=mylogin&password=mypassword) [function.readfile]: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\xampp\htdocs\dl\downloaders\rapidshare_com.php on line 25
```

According to the Rapidshare API, there's no way to stop it returning an SSL response.

Do I need to configure some special wrapper to handle this or something?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not sure if I should help you in your download of "Red.Riding.Hood.2011.R5.XviD-BiDA.part1.rar"

Comment: You need a PHP version with compiled in ssl support as the error message says. Otherwise use `curl` instead of `readfile`. That's two different things.

Comment: How would I go about using cURL? I'd rather use cURL over readfile if I could. Afaik though cURL can only download the file right to a file, instead of streaming it.

Comment: @RRStoyanov how would that help? I'm not using cURL to send the file to the user, I'm using the PHP `readfile()` function.

Answer (score 1):

libCurl is used to download file from a remote server like as readfile(http://....).

Though it can handle finer details like as cookie, post and ssl certificates. read more at http://cn.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

enable curl in php.ini and try the following code :

```
$ch=curl_init("http://rs$server_id$short_host.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=download&fileid=$file_id&filename=$file_name&login={$account['username']}&password={$account['password']}");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true); // follow http redirect
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,true); //temporary ignore certificate error for easier testing
$data=curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: curl_setoption is now curl_setopt